# Vuejs: Dependency not found despite being installed

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to use the [number-to-spanish-words NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-spanish-words) in my Vuejs component.

I installed the dependency via Vue UI. I can see it in my dependency list, in file `package.json` and `yarn.lock` and also in the `node_modules` folder.

Despite the module being installed, I'm still getting the following error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* number-to-spanish-words in ./node_modules/vuetify-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--4!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/MyComponent.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save number-to-spanish-words
```

This is how I try to use the dependency in `MyComponent.vue`:

```
<template>

  ...

</template>

<script>

const numberToSpanishWords = require('number-to-spanish-words');

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",

  ...
};

</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Don't use require, for starters. It's unknown what's your setup. Since you see that the module physically exists, the rest depends on your case.

Comment: @EstusFlask Can you be more specific? Why not use require and what do you need to know about my setup?

Comment: Because you use ES modules. Use import. require is not spec-compliant. Generally you need to provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's unknown what exactly happened when you " installed the dependency via Vue UI". It can be guessed that it's Vue *CLI* UI, because Vue itself is frontent framework, nothing else. But here I'm quite sure that it's the dep itself. You can see here that the latest version is dummy release https://unpkg.com/browse/number-to-spanish-words@1.1.0/ , use another one. Generally I'd suggest to pick another one that is not unmaintained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @EstusFlask, the package I tried to use was defective. I used [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spanish-number?activeTab=readme) instead.